# CDN for multiple domains with mod_pagespeed (Apache)

Tags: optimization, cdn, mod-pagespeed

I have a vps server with multiple sites and I have a cdn that is accessible by:
example.gocache.com

All of these sites are enabled to use this CDN however, I wanted mod_pagespeed to automatically change the urls of the images.
If an image has this URL:

http://www.example.com/pic.png

For this:

http://example.gocache.com/www.example.com/pic.png

Did you understand what I meant?

But there is something else too, I just wanted mod_pagespeed to do this automatically in files of the following extension: gif, jpeg, jpg and png.
Which are just images.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [MapRewriteDomain](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/domains#mapping_rewrite)

> Examples of why this might be desirable include: ... To move content to a Content
>   Delivery Network (CDN)